# How to tackle this carpenter ant ingress point?

Tags: pest-control, ants

Since moving into a new house about 6 weeks ago, we've occasionally seen small black ants indoors. We see about 5 a week on average. They don't seem to be doing anything specific indoors, i.e. they're not pillaging the dry goods cupboard. We keep the place pretty clean, food sealed, and we've never seen them in the kitchen area.

However, I did discover that there are some gaps in the sealant around one of the windows, and ants are coming and going from there. I assume it's the same group of ants and some of them are exploring further indoors. Next to the window are some vines with aphids living on them that the ants appear to be quite feeding on. I gather carpenter ants will eat honeydew created by aphids. If I watch for a while, I'll see the odd ant come or go through one of two small holes in the caulking of the window.

I think these are carpenter ants based on appearance and size. Most of them are around 6-8mm long, but I caught a couple yesterday that measured 9 and 13mm long.

I don't suspect a large scale infestation because I rarely see them indoors, and I've seen no evidence of frass (sawdust expelled from tunnels in wood by the ants).

So, I'm wondering how to tackle this issue. I see three main options, two of them DIY:

1. Use either Borax- or Diatomaceous-earth-based slow-acting powders/ baits around the opening they're using, with the hopes that those either kill off the colony if I've got one inside that wall, or just make the area inhospitable enough that the ants move on if this is just a shelter point for them when feeding on the aphids. In parallel, cut back the vines/ spray aphids to eliminate that food source. Once the ants are gone, seal the holes with [pest deterrent expanding foam](https://www.greatstuff.dupont.com/products/greatstuff-pro-pestblock.html) and fresh caulking.
2. Use fast-acting ant killer like [Wilson foaming spray](https://www.wilsoncontrol.com/en/products/insect-control/wilson-one-shot-jet-foam-ant-killer), just pump a generous amount into those holes, give that a day or two to do its thing, then again seal with the pest-resistant foam and caulking, and in parallel try to reduce the aphids.
3. Third option is just get a pest professional in right away.

My worry with #1 is it may just not work and may take a while (multiple weeks?) to determine it's not working. Reviews on Borax/ Diotemaceous based approaches seem very mixed. My worry with #2 is that the foaming pesticide leaves a lot of ants alive and now sealed inside, forcing them to tunnel out elsewhere, possibly further into the house.

Any thoughts on the above options or alternatives would be appreciated. FYI, I'm located in Ottawa, Canada, in case geography is relevant.

Here are some pictures:

The window - the vines and ingress points are in the lower left corner:

[image: Window]

Ingrress points - I've only seen ants coming and going here:

[image: Ingress Points]

Ants tending aphids:

[image: Ants and aphids]

Ant close up - I'm pretty sure these are carpenter ants:

[image: Ants and aphids close up]

Comment: a properly-mixed borax-based _bait_ won't take weeks; you should see fewer in a day or two and none in a week. You don't need to kill all the ants right away, in fact that will make eradication harder. You need to kill the egg-laying queen, and larvea, since those can be fashioned into a new queen. Once that's done, the drone workers will soon die off if your place is clean. I'm sure a lot of folks mixing boric acid themselves use too much, an understandable emotion, but one that kills the help too soon, on the way back to the nursery to feed the babies. Let them feed.

Comment: Also, consider using Triazicide after they are gone to prevent new bugs.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the input. I was worried it would take along time to determine if a borax based solution was working. I picked up a couple of types of Borax based off-the-shelf baits, and also bought Borax (Mule Team 20 brand) and sugar. Any thoughts on pre-made baits vs DIY?

Comment: Also, does it make sense to try to kill/ drive off the aphids at the same time? I'm thinking yes since that food source will be gone, making the ants more inclined to check out the baits.

Comment: I would offer them a buffet of your pre-mixed baits. That will indicate what they are attracted to. Expect to see a feeding frenzy, which is good; don't smoosh any whilst they feed or you'll scare them off. Once the bait or ants are gone, the powder is a good physical attack to prevent re-infestation. An ant walking though the powder for an inch or two will die pretty quickly after (faster than bait), before he can report back to base about the food+water paradise in your home. I don't know much about aphids, but i've fixed ants and roaches many times with boric acid, even in a chicago apt...

Comment: we used to have a house where ants would come into the basement ... all we did was to vacuum up as many as we could find ... that stopped them from coming in for about a week ... then they would forget that their buddies did not return and we would spend a few minutes vacuuming again

Comment: if you kill the aphids, then the ants will probably bring more to replace them

Comment: @jsotola Interesting point. I'll keep an eye on that. I put some Borax-based ant baits (Terro brand) out yesterday and cut back a lot of the vines that had aphids on them. I'm hoping that a) the fact that the ants were feeding off the aphids so enthusiastically means they're in a sweet food mood (apparently not always the case for carpenters), so will be more likely to go for the baits which are generally sweet based, and b) reducing the number of aphids will make the ants more open to alternative sweet sources, e.g. the baits. We'll see!